# Replace number into character from string using python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a string like this

```
        convert_text = "tet1+tet2+tet34+tet12+tet3"
```

I want to replace digits into character from above string.That mapping list available separately.so,When am trying to replace digit 1 with character 'g' using replace like below

```
       import re
       convert_text = convert_text.replace('1','g')
       print(convert_text)
```

output is

```
      "tetg+tet2+tet34+tetg2+tet3"
```

How to differentiate single digit and two digit values.Is there is any way to do with Regexp or something else?

Comment: take a look at regex

Comment: Is "34" a single replacement or two replacements of "3" and "4"?

Comment: i want to 34 as single replacement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regular expression with a callable replacement argument to substitute consecutive runs of digits with a value in a lookup table, eg:

```
import re

# Input text
convert_text = "tet1+tet2+tet34+tet12+tet3"

# to->from of digits to string
replacements = {'1': 'A', '2': 'B', '3': 'C', '12': 'T', '34': 'X'}

# Do actual replacement of digits to string
converted_text = re.sub('(\d+)', lambda m: replacements[m.group()], convert_text)
```

Which gives you:

```
'tetA+tetB+tetX+tetT+tetC'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
convert_text = "tet1+tet2+tet34+tet12+tet3"
pattern = re.compile(r'((?<!\d)\d(?!\d))')
convert_text2=pattern.sub('g',convert_text)
```

convert_text2
Out[2]: 'tetg+tetg+tet34+tet12+tetg'

You have to use negative lookahead and negative lookbehind patterns which are in between parenthesis

```
(?!pat) and 
(?<!pat),
```

you have the same with = instead of ! for positive lookahead/lookbehind.

EDIT: if you need replacement of strings of digits, regex is

```
pattern2 = re.compile(r'\d+')
```

In any pattern you can replace \d by a specific digit you need.